# How the new page life cycle events works?

Tags: javascript, onsen-ui

On onsen-ui v1.3.14, the doc describes new [page life cycle events](https://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#Pagelifecycle).

I can't get this to work. As described, the old event `pageinit` is still well fired but not the new events `init`, `destroy`, `show` and `hide`.

Is there a subtility I didn't notice ?

Comment: Page life cycle events were included in the beta version of Onsen UI 2.0, so they are not available for Onsen UI 1.x. Looks like the docs were merged when the beta was released. We should add that it's only for 2.0, sorry for the inconvenience!